# How to calculated Working Hours over 17 week period

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to work out How many field engineers work over 48 hours over a 17 week period. (by law you cannot work over 48 hours over a 17 week period) 
I managed to run the query for 1 Engineer but when I run it without an Engineer filter my query is very slow. 
I need to get the count of Engineers working over 48 hours and count under 48 hours then get an Average time worked per week.

Note: I am doing a Union on SPICEMEISTER & SMARTMEISTER because they are our old and new databases.

•   How many field engineers go over the 48 hours 
•   How many field engineers are under the 48 hours 
•   What is the average time worked per week for engineers

```
    SELECT DS_Date  
        ,TechPersNo
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            SMDS.EPL_DAT as DS_Date
           ,EN.pers_no as TechPersNo
        FROM    
            [SpiceMeister].[FS_OTBE].[EngPayrollNumbers] EN
        INNER JOIN
            [SmartMeister].[Main].[PlusDailyKopf] SMDS
                ON RIGHT(CAST(EN.[TechnicianID] AS CHAR(10)),5) = SMDS.PRPO_TECHNIKERNR
        WHERE     
        SMDS.EPL_DAT >= '2017-01-01'
        and
                  SMDS.EPL_DAT < '2018-03-01'

UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT
             SPDS.DailySummaryDate as DS_Date
            ,EN.pers_no as TechPersNo

        FROM
            [SpiceMeister].[FS_OTBE].[EngPayrollNumbers] EN
        INNER JOIN 
            [SpiceMeister].[FS_DS_BO].[DailySummaryHeader] SPDS
                ON EN.TechnicianID = SPDS.TechnicianID
        WHERE 
                  SPDS.DailySummaryDate >= '2018-03-01'


    ) as Techa
    where TechPersNo = 850009
) Tech
cross APPLY
```

Fast results

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This is not answerable currently because there isn't enough information. People need more than a big query to understand the problem. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is a great place to start.

Comment: Thank you and apologies for the lack of into. I am still getting used to SO. I will redo my post.

Answer (score 0):

The slowness is definitely due to the use of cross apply with a correlated subquery.  This will force the computation on a per-row basis and prevents SQL Server from optimizing anything.

This seems more like it should be a 'group by' query, but I can see why you had trouble making it up on account of the complex cumulative calculation in which you need output by person and by date, but the average involves not the date in question but a date range ending on the date in question.

What I would do first is make a common query to capture your base data between the two datasets.  That's what I do in the 'dailySummaries' common table expression below.  Then I would join dailySummaries onto itself matching by the employee and selecting the date range required.  From that, I would group by employee and date, aggregating by the date range.

```
with

    dailySummaries as (

        select      techPersNo = en.pers_no,
                    ds_date = smds.epl_dat,
                    dtDif = datediff(minute, smds.abfahrt_zeit, smds.rueck_zeit)
        from        smartMeister.main.plusDailyKopf 
        join        smartMeister.main.plusDailyKopf smds
                        on right(cast(en.technicianid as char(10)),5) = smds.prpo_technikernr
        where       smds.epl_dat < '2018-03-01'

        union all
        select      techPersNo = en.pers_no,
                    dailySummaryDate,
                    datediff(minute,
                        iif(spds.leaveHome < spds.workStart, spds.leaveHome, spds.workStart),
                        iif(spds.arrivehome > spds.workEnd, spds.arrivehome, spds.workEnd)
                    )
        from        spiceMeister.fs_ds_bo.dailySummaryHeader spds 
        join        spiceMeister.fs_ds_bo.dailySummaryHeader spds 
                        on en.TechnicianID = spds.TechnicianID
        where       spds.DailySummaryDate >= '2018-03-01'

    )

    select      ds.ds_date,
                ds.techPersNo,
                AvgHr = convert(real, sum(dsPrev.dtDif)) / (60*17)
    from        dailySummaries ds
    left join   dailySummaries dsPrev 
                    on ds.techPersNo = dsPrev.techPersNo 
                    and dsPrev.ds_date between dateadd(day,-118, ds.ds_date) and ds.ds_date
    where       ds.ds_date >= '2017-01-01'
    group by    ds_date,
                techPersNo 
    order by    ds_date
```

I may have gotten a thing or two wrong in translation but you get the idea.

In the future, post a more minimal example.  The union of the two datasets from the separate databases is not central to the problem you were trying to ask about.  A lot of the date filterings aren't core to the question.  The special casting in your join match logic is not important.  These things cloud the real issue.

Comment: Thank you very much @pwilcox
Appreciate your advice.